# ODBC ADO "брошеные" коннекты

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

В процессе работы накапливается порядка 1000 коннектов к базе. Сервера начинают хуже работать. Как сделать что б старые коннекты рвались сами?

1. База данных подключена к сайту посредством ODBC. Посетителей более 10 000 в день. К сайту на С# по всем правилам используя using(){} подключена база MSSQL база через ODBC. При этом, на сервере MSSQL "зависает" более 400 коннектов и соответственно открытых сокетов, которые непонятно используются или нет.
2. Подключена база через АDO+ODBC с MSSQL к информикс. Тут ещё веселее, за день может открытся 1000 коннектов, а в процессе работы часто около 7000. Создаётся впечатление будто у ODBC не работает уборщик мусора или он игнорирует команду close/release  интерфейсов работы с СУБД.

Коннект с MSSQL
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=10.0.0.79;Initial Catalog=mybase;User ID=user;Password=passw;Connect Timeout=900;Command Timeout=900

Коннект с Информикс настроен через алиас и SetNet32.
Server=myserv HostName=10.0.0.200 Service=Turbo protocol=olsoctcp
Система на серверах СУБД - windows-2008 server 64bit.

Comment: Открытые коннекты - это нормальные последствия connection pooling.    Сервера не начинают от них "хуже работать". Альтернатива - каждый раз открывать физическое соединение с сервером, что достаточно медленно. Вам стоит поискать настоящую причину "ухудшения", если оно хоть как-то проявляется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я достаточно много писал мелких выгрузок, и как правило они были разовыми программами, и практически никогда не делал Close. Он обычно происходил сам (по завершению работы программы), и проблем с этим небыло

```
EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Connection', @ado OUT, 1
if @hr=0 exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @ado, 'Open', NULL, 'MyConn'
if @hr=0 EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @ado, 'Execute', @rs OUT, @sql
set @eof = 1
if @hr=0 exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @rs, 'EOF', @eof out
-- код
if @rs is not null  exec sp_OAMethod @rs, 'Close' -- Добавил
if @rs is not null  exec sp_OADestroy @rs
if @db is not null  exec sp_OAMethod @db, 'Close' -- Добавил
if @db is not null  exec sp_OADestroy @db
if @ado is not null  exec sp_OAMethod @db, 'Close' -- Добавил
if @ado is not null exec sp_OADestroy @ado
```

Так как скрипт работает через службу (потому что, его выполняет MSSQL сервер), то служба почему то не закрывает ни один из коннектов.  Добавив Close коннект закрывается.

Answer (score 1):

Не занимался этим сам, но вообще в строке подключения есть следующие параметры:

- Connection pooling
- MinPoolSize
- MaxPoolSize

По идее, эти параметры должны управлять пулом подключений и ограничивать количество активных подключений к базе от одной строки подключений. Можно попробовать изучить рекомендации по установке данных параметров и подобрать подходящие значения.